# Android app unable to decode images for some users

Tags: android, decode, bitmapfactory

I have an app that reads and enhances photos. Recently I (forced by Google) updated my app to use sdk 33.  When I released it I began to get reports of errors.  For these users it will not read any old photos, but can still use the camera to take a picture and use the photo in the app.  It is able to save the photo.  The users who reported problems (only 4 so far) have different types of phones: pixel 6 and 7, Samsung s21 Ultra.  The error they get is "Unable to decode file".

I have tested it on my Pixel 5a, and various old Samsung phones.  Also on some virtual phones in android studio chipmunk.  It works fine for me.
Does anyone know what is going on?  Any advice how I can figure this out?
Should I update to the latest android studio?  Could that affect this?

New I Have found this on Google permissions: For a more privacy preserving experience for users, we’re introducing the Photo and Video Permissions policy to reduce the number of apps permitted to request broad photo/video permissions (READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO). Apps may only access photos and videos for purposes directly related to app functionality. Apps that have a one-time or infrequent need to access these files are requested to use a system picker, such as the Android photo picker. (effective August 31, 2024)

Here is the code

```
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFilePath, options);
            } catch (Throwable t){
                bmp = null;
                showError("Out of memory error.  Reduce MPixel limit in settings.");
            }


            if (bmp == null) {
                showError("Unable to decode file." + photoFilePath);
                photoFilePath = null;
                return;
            }



    //this is how photoFilePath gets set
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                photoFilePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

//                    showDiag("Image string " + photoFilePath);

//                    bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            } else {
                showDiag("You haven't picked an image");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showError("Something went wrong");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: How are you getting the value for `photoFilePath`?

Comment: The error message is one that you have defined. It would be of more help if you would not ignore the Throwable containing the error information what failed when executing `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`. So please first change your code and log that error, and when you have the Throwable class, the error message and the stack trace come back and include it in your question. Until that happens I recommend to close this question.

Comment: I added the code that gets photoFilePath above.  Hard to get the 4 users that have reported the problem to do complicated debugging.

Comment: I found an old version which used SDK 31.  Works fine for the people that had problems.  So to recap: my app was working fine for everyone, Google forced me to update to 33.  I updated my app to use 33 and it tested fine for me and a few phones I have around.  As it was updated for users I got some reports that it wouldn't read their old photos, but could take pictures and read them. Are there any anti-virus apps that might cause this?

Comment: you should have a look at what `throwable t` actually says, when it fails to decode the file?